# "Give the output that would be seen in the Eclipse console window" (Explanation needed)

Tags: java, swing, applet

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

 public class S17Exam2Q5 extends JApplet {
      int x = 5, y = 100, z = 15;
      public void init( {
         int x = z;
         char z = 'X';
         x = x - 3;
         System.out.println("1: x, y, and z are "+x+" "+y+" "+z);

         if (x <= y) {
             x = 50;
             y = y - 5;
             int y = x + 3;
             z = 'Q';
             System.out.println("2: x, y, and z are "+x+" "+y+" "+z);
          }

          System.out.println("3: x, y, and z are "+x+" "+y+" "+z);

          procExt(int z);

          System.out.println("4: x, y, and z are "+x+" "+y+" "+z);
     }

     public void procExt(x) {
        z = 10;
        int x = 20;
        y = y + 1; 
        System.out.println("5: x, y, and z are "+x+" "+y+" "+z);
     }
}
```

According to the exam answer key, this should be the answer:

```
1: x, y, and z are 12, 100, X
2: x, y, and z are 50, 53, Q
3: x, y, and z are 50, 95, Q
5: x, y, and z are 20, 96, 10
4: x, y, and z are 50, 96, Q
```

The answer makes sense only for 1 and 2, it's at 3 that I get confused. Shouldn't 3 and 2 be the same since they print one after the other with nothing happening inbetween? And shouldn't it be the same for 5 and then 4?I was also a bit confused as to what was happening with the procExt subroutine The answer that I wrote is below (asterisks denote an incorrect answer)

```
1: x, y, and z are  12,  100,   X
2: x, y, and z are  50,   53,   Q
3: x, y, and z are  50,  *53*,  Q
5: x, y, and z are  20,  *54*,  10
4: x, y, and z are *20*, *54*, *10*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3: int y (last time used) was 53. This didn't overwrite y, which is still set to 95. println used the 'int' value, but the next time y was called defaults to the (non-int numerical value) 95, which the program still saved for y.

for #4 and #5: Are you meaning to list the problem as 1,2,3,4,5 ? You have 5 & 4 backward both times, so I will refer to them in the order I see it (1,2,3,5,4)

It makes the most sense to do #5 Last, even though I listed them otherwise.

5: x is set using an int = 20, so this time reading for x will be 20, y = y + 1 will push y to 96 (and stays there for 4) and z = 10 because it is put there.

4: remember, #3 had x = 50, y = 95, z = Q. Notice proc() runs before 4. Using proc(int z) keeps the 'Q' value from #3 in z once. Because proc() was called, the y + 1 value calculates once to equal 96. And finally z = 10 because the (int z) call kept the contents of z at the value Q only once, the actual value of z is 'int' 20 at least once. This is due to int overloading previous values. The value get's popped after it is used.

Answer (score 0):

`init` is a method that overrides everything inside it developed from `JApplet`. What happens there is just an override on if's scope. When you initialize an existing variable on init, java will accept it as new variable that has same name on its scope.

Answer (score 0):

The reason 2 & 3 are different is because the the "y" in #2 is based on the statement `int y = x + 3;` which only exists within the scope of its `if` statement. Line #3 is based on the statement `y = y - 5;` but it exists outside the scope of the `if` statement because it is declared before that if statement begins (code line 5).

The difference between 5 & 4 is the similar, different scopes. #5 uses the `x` declared in the `procExt(x)` method, this is a different `x` used in #4.